# Exclude weekends from dynamic range of dates

Tags: excel, dynamic, range, date-range

I have built an OFFSET formula for a dynamic range that represents an array of dates from a list. Based on todays date, it takes the dates starting from a Monday X weeks ago until Friday Y weeks forward. Everything is jolly aside from the fact that I want to exclude the weekend dates from my array output.

My orginal data sometime has multiple occurances of dates, i.e.

```
04/03/2013 = Mo
05/03/2013 = Tu
06/03/2013 = We
06/03/2013 = We
07/03/2013 = Th
08/03/2013 = Fr
09/03/2013 = Sa
10/03/2013 = Su
11/03/2013 = Mo
12/03/2013 = Tu
```

This is my dynamic range. Calendar!$D:$D is where all dates in the above format are found.

```
=OFFSET(Calendar!$D$1,MATCH(TODAY()+1-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)-14,Calendar!$D:$D,0)-1,0,MATCH(TODAY()+28-WEEKDAY(TODAY()+1),Calendar!$D:$D,0)-MATCH(TODAY()+1-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)-14,Calendar!$D:$D,0)+1)
```

Given today's date, it finds Monday from two weeks ago, and then expands the range to Friday 3 weeks forwards. How can I make the dynamic range exclude weekends?

Comment: I cannot change the layout of the source sheet, but I could make the cells with weekend values blank. Don't know how much that helps. I tried using an IF weekend date then "" condition on the OFFSET function, which does work, but it leaves blank cells in the array rather than mergin the column to one consistent flow

Comment: Just thinking, what about using `na()` instead of `""`, or you can have three offset functions instead of one to remove the weekends?

Comment: Actually, I just removed all the weekend dates. Did not want to touch them because it would ruin another sheet, but I changed the formulas in that one and now both my sheets work. In response to your comment: I don't believe dynamic ranges can be a concatenated set of offset functions. As for NA(), it would work just as the blanks, i.e. weekend dates would be substituted by NA() in the output array. Although I have found a workaround, I would still be still keen on finding a solution.

Comment: I'm not at my pc but I'd love to try a few things out....

Comment: If you find a solution I will be very happy!

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a list of dates - this formula will generate the same array of dates (Monday to Friday only) without referring to a worksheet list

`=WORKDAY(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)-14,ROW(INDIRECT("1:30")))`

works in Excel 2007 or later

Given your comment below I assume the above won't work so an alternative approach to extract just the weekdays from the list between the two dates can work like this:

`=SMALL(IF((Range>=Start)*(Range<=End)*(WEEKDAY(Range,2)<6),Range),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUM((Range>=Start)*(Range<=End)*(WEEKDAY(Range,2)<6)))))`

That will give you all the weekdays in ascending order (regardless of order on the list) where Range is your list of dates, Start is the required start date and End is the required end date - I can put more detail on it if you want to pursue that method.....

Comment: How does the INDIRECT("1:30") element work? Formula does not work for me, and moreover I do not see how it could recognize weeks where certain dates recur more than one time.

Comment: OK - my mistake - I didn't notice repeated date, so they need to be taken from list but without the Sats and Suns? ROW(INDIRECT("1:30")) just generates an array of numbers 1 to 30 assuming you wanted 30 dates (6 weeks Mon-Fri) but that's moot if you have repeats......

Comment: Unfortunately the case is that there are repeated dates, hence the need to extract all non-Sat&Sun dates.

Comment: OK thanks, I edited  my reply to show a generic method for doing that